# Content behind overlay HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a hero section for a layout. My problem is that the content (text and buttons) is being obscured by the overlay even after setting a higher z-index value.

Here's my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap');

/* Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Base Styles */

:root {
  --primary-color: #c72727;
  --secondary-color: #f99500;
  --light-color: #f3f3f3;
  --dark-color: #333;
  --max-width: 1100px;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: var(--light-color);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
}

i.fab {
  color: #777;
}

p {
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
  margin-bottom: 0.55rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

/* Utilities */
.container {
  max-width: var(--max-width);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary,
.bg-primary {
  background: var(--primary-color);
}

.btn-secondary,
.bg-secondary {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
}

.btn-dark,
.bg-dark {
  background: var(--dark-color);
}

.bg-light {
  background: var(--light-color);
}

.category {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.category-sports {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
}
.category-entertainment {
  background: #a66bbe;
}
.category-tech {
  background: #009cff;
}

/* Header */

#header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#header .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 6fr 3fr 2fr;
  align-items: center;
}

#header .logo {
  width: 180px;
}

#header ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#header ul li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Showcase */

#showcase {
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background: url('../images/featured.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  position: relative;
}

#showcase::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#showcase * {
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>NewsGrid | The Leading Online News Website</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="social">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Showcase -->
    <section id="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="showcase-content">
          <span class="category category-sports">Sports</span>
          <h1>Some Sports Article</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus
            rerum officia quibusdam mollitia deserunt animi soluta laudantium.
            Quam sapiente a dolorum magnam necessitatibus quis tempore facere
            totam. Dolor, sequi distinctio!
          </p>
          <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-primary">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did set the Z-index for the showcase content to be in front of the image, but it doesn't work. I have tried an identical approach elsewhere and that works.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: `#showcase * {
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
}` put position `relative` .You need to have position other than `static` for z-index to work

Comment: As far as i know You need to have position other than `static` for z-index to work and by default position is `static`

Comment: Yes, you're right. It works on either a positioned element or if using display: flex, in which case you don't need to add position: relative. That explains it! Cheers for the help :)